# Create column based on another column in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table that has 50 billion rows (~10 TB) and ~40 columns. This table has a timestamp column that's always filled. I need to create a new date column and backfill all values for it.

This query works, but it's really inefficient (it takes 1 hour to scan 1%, with 2XL warehouse). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
UPDATE DAILY_TABLE b
SET b.ts_date = to_date(a.ts_tstamp)
FROM
    (SELECT a.ts_date, a.ts_tstamp 
     FROM DAILY_TABLE a) a;
```

Current table:

| ts_tstamp | ts_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-28 05:01:32.883 | null |
| 2021-01-28 05:01:32.883 | null |
| 2020-01-25 05:01:32.883 | null |

Desired table:

| ts_tstamp | ts_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-28 05:01:32.883 | 2021-04-28 |
| 2021-01-28 05:01:32.883 | 2021-01-28 |
| 2020-01-25 05:01:32.883 | 2020-01-25 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column does not need to be materialized and is always dependent on ts_tstamp then another option could be a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE DAILY_TABLE
ADD COLUMN ts_date_virtual DATE AS TO_DATE(ts_tstamp);
```

Comment: Be very careful when you do this. The table at this point will start behaving partially like a view, which most SQL users are not familiar with.

And if you are to drop the `ts_tstamp`, Snowflake will happily do it for you without complaining and fail only when you try selecting the virtualised column `ts_date_virtual`.